# How to implement a placeholder UI as launch screen

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

I was looking for a way to implement a launch screen. I finally found the best solution possible, which was posted by Ian Lake [here](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/SW7F2CJvAmU). However, it explains how to implement a **branded launch screen**, not a **placeholder UI**. You can see the difference [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/launch-screens.html#).

I need the placeholder UI because my app doesn't take a lot of time to start. It's almost the same as the normal start screen, just with and added toolbar. I have done everything needed, I just need to know how the layer list should be. It would consist on a top shape of primary color and a gradient below.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quick fix available at https://medium.com/@lucasurbas/placeholder-ui-launch-screen-d85c35552119

Surprisingly, this is the expected behaviour.